# Python circular import error, though no double imports

Tags: python, fastapi

I am running a FastAPI project in which I would like to encapsulate all my api routers in 1 file, however for some reason it keeps saying I have a circular import when I try to start my main, I have been renaming my router files and the router handler, but all with no avail. The only package that I import twice is the APIRouter from FastAPI, but this shoulldn't be a problem I think. Any help would be very much appreciated!

My main file:

```
import os

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

from db import database
from resources.routes import api_router_handler

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(api_router_handler)


@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
    await database.connect()

@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown():
    await database.disconnect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

resources/routes

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
from resources.auth import router

api_router_handler = APIRouter()
api_router_handler.include_router(router)
```

resources/auth

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

from managers.User import UserManager

router = APIRouter(tags="Auth")

@router.post("/register", status_code=201)
async def register(user_data):
    token = UserManager.register(user_data)
    return {"token": token}
```

managers/User.py

```
from asyncpg import UniqueViolationError
from passlib.context import CryptContext
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException

from db import database
from managers.auth import AuthManager
from models import user
```

My file structure

[image]

Error rrace back from Pycharm
[image]

Comment: What does your `Users.py` file import?

Comment: Let me add it in the main topic for readability

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Added the traceback to the topic, thanks for having  a look

Comment: So, why does `managers/auth.py` have `from main import jwt_secret`? What is the `main` and `jwt_secret`?

Comment: it's this line, which I originally took out from security reasons, changed the secret key for now: jwt_secret = os.environ.get('jwt_secret', 'a')

Comment: But that is your circular import. You must break that link.

Comment: Thanks a lot, That indeed solved my issue moving it to auth.py though I do not totally understand why. can I never reimport anything from main.py?

Comment: In python, imports cannot be circular. Circular imports would lead to an infinite loop in the python interpreter. This restriction is commonly found in many computer languages.

Comment: You could import it from main _as long as it has been defined before you import the other module_. So if you import `jwt_secret` from main, the file that imports `jwt_secret` has to be imported _after_ `jwt_secret` has been defined.

Comment: Looking at the traceback, in `main.py` you're importing `api_router_handler`, then in `managers/auth.py` you're importing `jwt_secret` again from main.py, resulting in a circular import.